# Making Shechiyanu on new Tefilin

Tags: halacha, blessing, tefilin

If one purchases a new pair of Tefilin should he say Shechiyanu when he puts them on the first time? When is the Bracha said for those that say 2 Brachos, after the first Bracha of L'haniach Tefilin or after the second Bracha of Al Mitzvas Tefilin (before or after Baruch Shem)?

Comment: Not everyone says two brachot.

Comment: This is amazingly relevant as I just purchased a new pair of tefilin which will be arriving tomorrow!

Comment: @Daniel Don't forget to CYLOR for a final ruling

Comment: @doubleaa of course :)

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=12847) and [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/07/11/shehecheyanu-for-tefillin/) this is a Machlokes. The Mishna Brurah paskens that you should say Shehechianu on something else to avoid the doubt, but to find a way to say the Bracha (apparently not when actually wearing the Tefillin).

[Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=xOt6IAYWp5YC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=shehechiyanu%20on%20tefillin&source=bl&ots=3eTpGMePSf&sig=7149Ovsrd6mdgCxooif3DkdCTus&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lLiYU-Vq1syxBMn2gpAF&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=shehechiyanu%20on%20tefillin&f=false) it says that you could wear a new garment if you normally make a Shehechiyanu on it, at which point you make the Bracha after both Brochos. The source footnote isn't available in the Google preview.

Comment: I would have to think it would be after the Baruch Shem, as this is intended to be connected to the second Bracha, and slipping in a Shehechiyanu in-between would seem to be a problem, but I didn't find a source.

Comment: To be clear, the MB's psak would only apply if this is your first time putting on Tefillin ever, but not if the Tefillin are just new (unless you wrote/built them).

Answer (score -1):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch chapter 59. 11) "When you buy new sacred books, you need not say shecheyanu, as the things which you perform mitzvos are not for physical enjoyment." Based on this I don't think one would say shehechiyanu for the purchase of new tefillin.

Comment: Do you say shehechiyanu when you shake lulav or blow shofar?