# Shechechyanu for Teffilin?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, shehecheyanu

Can or should one make a shehecheyanu on a new pair of telillin even if it has been received at an earlier date but not worn as of yet?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40249/759

Comment: I agree. Can someone close this?