# A barmitzvah boy saying shehechiyanu on new tefillin when wearing them prior to barmitzvah

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, tefilin, shehecheyanu

Following on from this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40249/making-shechiyanu-on-new-tefilin) and assuming that you make the bracha of shehechiyanu on new tefillin...

If a barmitzvah boy has the custom to start wearing his tefillin early. So for example, in Litvak circles the practise to wear them a month early (see [Aruch HaShulchan 37:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.37.4?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en), [Piskei Teshuvos 37 - Footnote 26](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/164305/p/386/t/4866133068650112341234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c), [Nitei Gavriel on Hilchos Barmitzvah](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46541&st=&pgnum=221&hilite=)), or like others do; 2-3 months prior to barmitzvah (see [Magen Avraham 37:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.37.4?lang=bi&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Orach%20Chayim&lang2=en), [Shulchan Aruch HaRav 37:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3284483/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-37-Time-for-Wearing-Tefillin.htm#v3), [Chayei Adam 66:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam.66.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Is it better for the boy to say the shehechiyanu:

1. The first time he puts on the tefillin on - i.e. the same way he makes the bracha on putting tefillin on even though he is not yet barmitzvah (refer to [Nitei Gavriel 34:3](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46541&st=&pgnum=232&hilite=))

or

2. Does one wait until the boy actually becomes barmitzvah and then says it as a fully fledged "man"? i.e. Regardless of the fact that he puts on tefillin early he still does not count towards a minyan ([Piskei Teshuvos 37:5](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/164305/p/386/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c))

Comment: If you know that it's a Mahlokes, why do you ask? And when do we refer to Halachah as "better"?

Comment: @AlBerko - I am asking for those who hold that one does make a bracha what does one do in the scenario of a barmitzvah boy?

Comment: And @AlBerko for the record there are times when you can do the halacha in a "better" way e.g. to do it lechatchila rather than b'dieved, or to do a mitzvah in a more mehadrin way...

Comment: Why not ask regarding a tallit gadol, which unambigously gets a shehechiyanu?

Comment: https://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after searching high and low I came across the *[Halachically Speaking](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol13Issue2.pdf)* (Vol. 13, Issue 2) on the topic of Barmitzvah and Tefillin - **see p.7**. [Rav Moishe Dovid Lebovitz](https://torahdownloads.com/s-257-rabbi-moishe-dovid-lebovits.html) there makes a clear distinction and helps to provide a very comprehensive answer and I have tried to link most the footnotes so everyone can easily access the sources.

He writes as follows:

> **Shehecheyanu**
>
> ---
>
> There is a discussion in the poskim if a bar mitzvah boy recites a Shehecheyanu when placing the tefillin for the first time. On one hand, he should recite a Shehecheyanu since it is an exciting time.<sup>1</sup> On the other hand, this brachah was only instituted for a recurring mitzvah.<sup>2</sup>
>
> If he starts before his bar mitzvah, no brachah of Shehecheyanu is recited.<sup>3</sup> Before bar mitzvah he is still a child, so he does not recite Shehecheyanu. When he becomes bar mitzvah, it is no longer his first time.<sup>4</sup> If he starts when he becomes thirteen, there is a debate regarding Shehecheyanu. Therefore, he should buy a new garment and make a Shehecheyanu on it, and have the tefillin in mind.<sup>5</sup>

---

> <sup>1</sup> [Rambam Hilchos Brachos 10:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Blessings.10.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Others say it is not a joy since one has to make sure to have a clean body ([Bach, O.C. 22](https://www.sefaria.org/Bach%2C_Orach_Chaim.22.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Sha’arei Teshuvah 22](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/143562/p/62/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); see Bar Mitzvah [Kroizer] pages 116-117). Refer to [Mor U’ketziah 27](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/141304/p/44/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); [Chinah D’chaya 89](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/102812/p/149/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); [Keren L’Dovid, O.C. 57](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/12144/p/158/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); [Chasam Sofer, O.C. 55](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/10992/p/67/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c).
>
> <sup>2</sup> Refer to [Shach, Y.D. 28:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.28.5.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en); [Y.D. 289:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.289.1.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en); [Levush, O.C. 22:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41186&st=&pgnum=23&hilite=); [Taz 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.22.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en); [Elyah Rabbah 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Eliyah_Rabbah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.22.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en); [Aruch Hashulchan 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.22.3?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en); [Machzik Brachah 2](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/8355/p/22/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); [Kaf Hachaim (Palagi) 10:8](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/925/p/139/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); [Yufei L’lev 22:1](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/8723/p/101/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); [Me’asef L’chol Hamachanos 19](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/7888/p/201/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); [Birur Halachah 22](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/104605/p/81/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); Chanoch L’na’ar page 37; [Halachah Berurah 22:5:footnote 12](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/143811/p/417/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); [Piskei Teshuvos 22](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/164305/p/238/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c):[footnotes 7](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/164305/p/239/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c), [10 in depth](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/164305/p/240/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); Yechaveh Da’as 2:31; [Chayei Moshe 37](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/52754/p/200/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c):page 182; [Mishneh Halachos 6:6](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/150997/p/18/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); Bar Mitzvah [Kroizer] pages 116-120 in depth.
>
> <sup>3</sup> [Eishel Avraham Butchatch 37](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40312&st=&pgnum=11&hilite=); [Likutei Maharich 1:page 19b (old)](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/12944/p/45/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); [Birur Halachah 22](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50532&st=&pgnum=85&hilite=); [Natei Gavriel Bar Mitzvah 37:6](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46541&st=&pgnum=244); [Lehoros Nassan 2:9](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/108195/p/28/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c).
>
> <sup>4</sup> [Eishel Avraham Butchatch 37](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40312&st=&pgnum=11&hilite=). See Chanoch L’na’ar 10:footnote 3.
>
> <sup>5</sup> [Biur Halachah 22, “koneh”](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.22.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Likutei Maharich 1:page 19b (old)](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/12944/p/45/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c), 22:page 31; Yechaveh Da’as 2:31; [Mishneh Halachos 6:6](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/150997/p/18/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c); Bar Mitzvah [Kroizer] pages 123-124; see [Yalkut Yosef 37:7](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/53699/p/676/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c). In regard to reciting a Shehecheyanu on tefillin of Rabbeinu Tam which one puts on for the first time, see Bar Mitzvah [Kroizer] page 124:footnote 18.

Comment: "Before bar mitzvah he is still a child, so he does not recite Shehecheyanu." This sentence is baffling. Children say shehechiyanu lots of times.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I think it means that he is a child and therefore not technically at an age when he is ראוי to put on tefillin and that is why is he doesn't recite shehechiyanu like I asked in my question.

Comment: That's not what you wrote in your question and it also makes no sense. He's doing the mitzva midin chinukh just like hearing shofar etc. When reading Megillah for a katan does he say Al Mikra Megillah and not shehechiyanu?? Of course not.